# Is there a plugin for feedback like Kissmetrics available?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, user-interface

Kissmetrics has a little widget thing that pops up from the bottom-right corner of the page, asking for comments or offering a short feedback survey.

Is there anything like this available for Wordpress for free? I'm on a shoestring and need a free plugin.

I don't mean a subscription-based service: just a plugin that can pop up a little form for feedback/ a survey, collecting and storing the data locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Pagerati.com we recommend the Total Feedback plugin to clients. You can find it at http://www.totalfeedback.net/

Comment: Thanks, but that's another paid-for plugin. If I'm on a shoestring, all I'm looking for is a plugin that can act like the popup from Kissmetrics, but collect the data locally.